# How to divide my data into distincts mini-batches randomly [JULIA]

Tags: julia

I have a vector of data of 100000 examples. The values are -1 and 1.
I want to get from this data **16 distinct mini-batches** randomly, each one of 6250.

Here is my code to generate the vector of 100000 examples which is stored in a file.

The question of how to divide my data to different parts is answered by Dan.

**Now, l want to store  [X[p] for p in parts] in p files. l mean by that : if l have 3 parts , l want to create and store the values of p. How can l do that ?**

```
workspace()
using JLD, HDF5
#import HTreeRBM

function gen_random(m,k)  

# m the length of the vector , for instance m=100000 and k the number of partitions let's set k=16

s = rand(m)
# Pkg.add("JLD"), Pkg.add("HDF5") these two packages are needed in order to store our vectors in files under the extension jld 

 # allow to convert each random number to -1 or 1

X=float_to_binary(s)



parts= kfoldperm(length(X),k)

for p in 1:length(parts)
file =jldopen(@sprintf("my path to file/mini_batch%d.jld", p),"w")
write(file, "X", [X[p] for p in parts]) 
close(file)
end
return [X[p] for p in parts]

            function float_to_binary(s,level=0.4)
      for i=1:length(s)
        s[i] = s[i] > level ? 1.0 : -1.0
      end
    file = jldopen("/home/anelmad/Desktop/stage-inria/code/HTreeRBM.jl/artificial_data/mydata.jld", "w")
    write(file, "s", s)  # alternatively, say "@write file A"
    close(file)
      return s
    end


           function kfoldperm(l,k)
    n,r = divrem(l,k)
    b = collect(1:n:l+1)
        for i in 1:length(b)
            b[i] += i > r ? r : i-1  
        end
    p = randperm(l)
       return [p[r] for r in [b[i]:b[i+1]-1 for i=1:k]]


    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Define `kfoldperm` by running:

```
function kfoldperm(N,k)
    n,r = divrem(N,k)
    b = collect(1:n:N+1)
    for i in 1:length(b)
        b[i] += i > r ? r : i-1  
    end
    p = randperm(N)
    return [p[r] for r in [b[i]:b[i+1]-1 for i=1:k]]
end
```

Now,

```
v = rand(10)
parts = kfoldperm(10,3)
[v[p] for p in parts]
```

Will give you a partition of `v` to 3 parts.

Comment: kflodperm(10,3) is not recognized by julia compiler. Is that function suppoerted by julia ?   what the parameter N, k, n r  represent ?   thank you for help

Comment: @samtzaurtis Note that Dan Getz defined the function `kfoldperm` above. It is not a built-in function.

Comment: The parameter `N` is the number of elements in the dataset. `k` is the number of parts. The return value is a vector with k elements. Each elements is a vector of indices (between 1 and N) which you can use as an index to the dataset.

Comment: when l run parts = kfoldperm(10,3) it returns this error   ERROR:                              MethodError: no method matching colon(::Int64, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1})
Closest candidates are:
  colon{T<:Real}(::T<:Real, ::Any, ::T<:Real)
  colon{A<:Real,C<:Real}(::A<:Real, ::Any, ::C<:Real)
  colon{T}(::T, ::Any, ::T)
       the problem comes from the line     b = collect(1:n:N+1)

Comment: l don't also understand what this line does for i in 1:length(b)
       b[i] += i > r ? r : i-1
   end

Comment: here is the answer of how permuting randomly a vector using collections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010052/julia-how-to-permute-randomly-a-vector-in-julia

Comment: From the error message, it seems you are calling `kfoldperm` with floating point vectors as parameters (which 10 and 3 in the example are not - try the exact example first and it will clear things up. Perhaps in a clean julia environment). As for the `b[i] += `... line, it adjust by 1 the length of some parts to account for the cases where the length of vector does not divide evenly by number of folds.

Comment: Looking at the code in the question, I can see you are calling the function with `Z=kfoldperm(Y,k)`. It should be `Z=kfoldperm(length(Y),k)`. The parameters are integers! And the next line should use `Z` instead of `parts`. `parts` was just the name of a variable with the return value of `kfoldperm`, which you changed to `Z`. And you are doing nothing with the partitioned vector. Try stuff in the REPL a bit to get a feeling for what the return value is.

Comment: thank you a lot Dan Getz. l understand better and it's working. But now l want to store  [v[p]]   in different files, in p different files. so if l have for examples 3 parts l want to creat  3 files to store the values of each part. hope that it's more clear.

Comment: l want to stor X[1] in file 1 , X[2] in file 2, X[3] in file 3...... in my loop l store all the X[1], X[2], X[3] in the different files

Comment: It might be best to have the file question in another separate StackOverflow question.

Comment: ok l do it. since it's related so l will only share the code related to the problem of storing values in files