# JULIA : How to permute randomly a vector in julia?

Tags: julia, permute

l have a vector of random numbers  that l want to permute randomly using randperm()  function as follows but it's not working.

```
X=rand(100000) # a vector of 100000 random elements
Y=randperm(X) # want to permute randomly the vector x
```

the returned error is :
**ERROR: MethodError: no method matching randperm(::Array{Float64,1})
 in eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:237**

Thank you

Comment: because randperm() is also used in matlab and julia language is a trade-off between matlab and python. actually the function is the same but l don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Use `shuffle()`

If your only goal is to randomly permute the vector, you can use [`shuffle()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.shuffle) (part of the `Random` module):

```
julia> using Random;

julia> X = collect(1:5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> shuffle(X)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 5
 4
 1
 2
 3
```

If you don't want to allocate a new vector, but want to shuffle in place, you can use `shuffle!()`:

```
julia> shuffle!(X);

julia> X
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 3
 4
 2
 5
 1
```

## `randperm()`

[`randperm()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Random.randperm) accepts an integer `n` and gives a permutation of length n. You can use this ordering to then reorder your original vector:

```
julia> X[randperm(length(X))]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4
 1
 2
 5
```

## Bonus: Sampling without replacement

You can also use [`StatsBase.sample()`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/sampling/#StatsBase.sample) to sample the same `length(X)` elements from your array without replacement:

```
julia> import StatsBase;

julia> StatsBase.sample(X, length(X), replace=false)
5-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 2
 4
 1
 3
```

Comment: thank you a lot , l just started learning julia. l appreciate your help

Comment: This is `Random.shuffle` btw. Or `using Random: shuffle`

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on the second point in the answer by @niczky12, if you want to randomly permute the vector `X` directly then it is actually more efficient to call `shuffle!(X)` instead of `shuffle(X)`:

```
# precompile @time
@time 1+1

# create random vector
p = 10_000
X = collect(1:p)

# reproducible shuffles
srand(2016)

shuffle(X)
@time shuffle(X)

shuffle!(X)
@time shuffle!(X)
```

Output on my machine:

```
  0.000004 seconds (148 allocations: 10.151 KB)
  0.000331 seconds (6 allocations: 78.344 KB)
  0.000309 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

The call to `shuffle!` allocates substantially less memory (160 bytes v. 78 Kb) and thus will scale better with `p`.

Comment: Don't use global variables when benchmarking, wrap everything in a function.  You can also use the BenchmarkTools package

Comment: Oh, maybe it doesn't matter here though

Comment: It shouldn't matter here since I sought to compare memory allocations and not compute times. It is good Julia coding practice to wrap everything in functions. On my machine, wrapping the script in a function does not change the result.