# JULIA : How can l write and store files in a loop ?

Tags: makefile, julia

l have a massive dataset that l divided into  k mini datasets where k=100. Know l want to store these mini datasets in different files.
to store my massive dataset l used the following instructions :

```
using JLD, HDF5
    X=rand(100000)
    file = jldopen("path to my file/mydata.jld", "w") # the extension of file is jld so you should add packages JLD and HDF5,  Pkg.add("JLD"), Pkg.add("HDF5"),
    write(file, "X", X)  # alternatively, say "@write file A"
    close(file)
```

Know l divided my dataset into k sub dataset  where k=100

```
function get_mini_batch(X)

    mini_batches = round(Int, ceil(X / 100))

            for i=1:mini_batches
                mini_batch = X[((i-1)*100 + 1):min(i*100, end)]
                file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata.jld", "w")
                write(file, "mini_batch", mini_batch)  # alternatively, say "@write file mini_batch"
                 lose(file)
            end
end
```

but this function allows to store the different sub dataset in one file which is overwritten at each iteration.

```
file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata1.jld", "w")  # at each iteration l want to get files : mydata1, mydata2 ... mydata100
file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata2.jld", "w")
file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata3.jld", "w")
file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata4.jld", "w")
.
.
.
file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata100.jld", "w")
```

Alternatively l tried out this procedure
 function get_mini_batch(X)

```
    mini_batches = round(Int, ceil(X / 100))

            for i=1:mini_batches
                mini_batch[i] = X[((i-1)*100 + 1):min(i*100, end)]
                file[i]= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata.jld", "w")
                write(file, "mini_batch", mini_batch)  # alternatively, say "@write file mini_batch"
                 lose(file)
            end
end
```

but l don't have the idea of how to make a variable i=1....100 within this line code  file[i]= jldopen("/path to my file/**mydata(i).jld**", "w")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [string formatting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Printf/#Printf.@sprintf).

To create the filenames, you can use `@sprintf()`. Then you can use these strings to write your objects to disk.

```
julia> using Printf  # Needed in Julia 1.0.0
julia> @sprintf("myfilename%02.d.jld", 5)
"myfilename05.jld"
```

Example in a loop:

```
julia> for i in 1:3
           println(@sprintf("myfilename%03.d.jl", i))
       end
myfilename001.jl
myfilename002.jl
myfilename003.jl
```

I used `%03.d` here to show how you can add leading zeros to your file names. This will help later on when it comes to sorting.

Comment: but how can l can open a file , write inside and store it  using @sprintf()   ?          like :                              file = jldopen("path to my file/mydata.jld", "w") # the extension of file is jld so you should add packages JLD and HDF5,  Pkg.add("JLD"), Pkg.add("HDF5"),
    write(file, "X", X)  # alternatively, say "@write file A"

Comment: You can use `@spritnf` to specify the filename. For example in your question, second code block replace:  `file= jldopen("/path to my file/mydata.jld", "w")` with `file= jldopen(@sprintf("/path to file/mydata%d.jld, i), "w")` where `i` is the number of minibatch you are looping over.

Comment: My question is related to this topic "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37989159/how-to-divide-my-data-into-distincts-mini-batches-randomly-julia". l want to create files to store X[P] values. How should l proceed to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with niczky12 that you are looking for string formatting. But I would personally write it this alternative way:

```
"/path to my file/mydata$i.jld"
```

instead of using `sprintf`.

Example:

```
julia> i = 4
4

julia> "/path/mydata$i.jld"
"/path/mydata4.jld"
```

Comment: Yep, this is the easy way. I just prefer to have the leading zeros in this case, hence I used `@sprintf`. :)